# Верно ли расставлены знаки?

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли расставлены знаки : "В понедельник, в 8 часов"?

Answer (score 1):

Возможны варианты, что определяется по ситуации.

1) ***Когда встречаемся? — В понедельник, в 8 часов.*** Отношения однородные, перечислены временные координаты.

2) ***В понедельник в 8 часов нужно быть на вокзале***. Отношения неоднородные (день и час), это единая координата времени.

Answer (score 1):

Если "в 8 часов" уточнение (часто в конце предложения), то запятая нужна:

*В какой день? — В понедельник, (а именно) в 8 часов.*

Если это общие данные, запятая не нужна:

*Когда? — В понедельник в 8 часов.*